# Drop the rows till we reach certain string as column name and append with another dataframe after doing the same in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([["M","N","O"],["A","B","C"],["X","Y","Z"],[2,3,4],[1,2,3]])
```

```
0   1   2
M   N   O
A   B   C
X   Y   Z
2   3   4
1   2   3
```

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([["P","Q","R","S"],["X","Z","W","Y"],[4,5,6,7],[7,8,9,3]])
```

```
0   1   2   3
P   Q   R   S
X   Z   W   Y
4   5   6   7
7   8   9   3
```

I want to read the 1st dataframe drop the rows till the row starts with **X** and make that row as column names, then read the 2nd dataframe again drop the rows till row starts with **X** then append it to the 1st dataframe. Repeat the process in loop because I have multiple such dataframes.

**Expected Output:**

```
df_out = pd.DataFrame([[2,3,4,0],[1,2,3,0],[4,7,5,6],[7,3,8,9]],columns=["X","Y","Z","W"])
```

```
X   Y   Z   W
2   3   4   0
1   2   3   0
4   7   5   6
7   3   8   9
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First test if value `X` exist in any row for all columns in shifted DataFrame for get all rows after match by [`DataFrame.cummax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cummax.html) with [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) and set columns names by this row in [`DataFrame.set_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html), same solution use for another DataFrame, join by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), replace missing values and for expected order add [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with unon both columns names:

```
m1 = df1.shift().eq('X').cummax().any(axis=1)
cols1 = df1[df1.eq('X').any(axis=1)].to_numpy().tolist()

df11 = df1[m1].set_axis(cols1, axis=1)

m2 = df2.shift().eq('X').cummax().any(axis=1)
cols2 = df2[df2.eq('X').any(axis=1)].to_numpy().tolist()

df22 = df2[m2].set_axis(cols2, axis=1)

df = (pd.concat([df11, df22], ignore_index=True)
        .fillna(0)
        .reindex(df11.columns.union(df22.columns, sort=False), axis=1))
print (df)
   X  Y  Z  W
0  2  3  4  0
1  1  2  3  0
2  4  7  5  6
3  7  3  8  9
```

Answer (score 1):

This works,

```
shift = 0

for index in df.index:
  if df.iloc[index - 1, 0] == "X":
    X = df.iloc[index - 1, :].values
    break
  shift -= 1

df = df.shift(shift).dropna()
df.columns = X
df
```

Output -

|  | X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 |